# In which situations std::dynamic_pointer_cast fails?

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem that's driving me crazy. I made a minimum verifiable example, but it does not show the error.

Let's first think about this code:

```cpp
class WhiteNoise: public ApplicableEffect  {
};
            
std::shared_ptr<ApplicableEffect> mod;
//...
std::shared_ptr<WhiteNoise> d = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<WhiteNoise>(this->mMod);
if (d) {
    d->something = static_cast<int>(4800 * value);
} else {
    ALOGE(TAG, "std::dynamic_pointer_cast<WhiteNoise> FAILURE!");
    if (this->mMod) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "this->mMmod is not null");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "this->mMmod IS null");
    }
}
```

Can this piece of code possibly log the failure considering that `this->mMod` is not null? `WhiteNoise` clearly inherits form `ApplicableEffect`.

On my program I get:

```
E/EffectDescr.h: std::dynamic_pointer_cast<WhiteNoise> FAILURE!
V/EffectDescr.h: this->mMmod is not null
```

Which means the failure is not because `mMod` is null. What could be the reason if `WhiteNoise` inherits from `ApplicableEffect`?

Here's the minimum verifiable example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
    
class ApplicableEffect {
public:
    virtual float operator()() {}
};
    
class DelayLineEffect {
public:
    DelayLineEffect(std::shared_ptr<ApplicableEffect> mMod): mMod(mMod) {}
    std::shared_ptr<ApplicableEffect> mMod;
};
    
class WhiteNoise: public ApplicableEffect  {
};
    
class WhiteChorusEffect: public DelayLineEffect {
public:
    WhiteChorusEffect(): DelayLineEffect(std::make_shared<WhiteNoise>()) {}

    void do_something() {
        auto d = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<WhiteNoise>(this->mMod);
        if (d) {
            std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "failure" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
    
int main() {
    WhiteChorusEffect whiteChorusEffect;
    whiteChorusEffect.do_something();
}
```

It works, but on my main program, I get the failure.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: "I made a minimum verifiable example but it does not show the error." This sounds like you're very close to isolating the cause of the problem. There are a bunch of confounding factors here. #1 is shared pointers.

Comment: "*I made a minimum verifiable example, but it does not show the error*" - that makes me think that maybe your main code has undefined behavior in it that just happens to be affecting the result of `dynamic_pointer_cast` unexpectedly.

Comment: If they code you are showing us doesn't cause the error, it will be very hard for anyone here to give you an answer.  Can you make a [mre] that does reproduce the error?

Comment: `virtual float operator()() {}` - Are you calling this at any point? If so ... UB

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm calling but not with this blank returned value

Comment: Ok, try to make a reproducible example (without these kinds of problems). Another thing that shouldn't matter, but `clang` seems to want it: `virtual ~ApplicableEffect() = default;`. I'm not sure why it complains here though.

Comment: Do you find out the reason? I seem to meet the same situation, and also I could not reproduce it with any snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the facts...

- `WhiteNoise` derives from `Applicable`
- `DelayLine` contains a pointer to an `Applicable`
- `WhiteChorus` derives from `DelayLine` and constructs the base class with a pointer to a `WhiteNoise` (not an `Applicable`, but derived from it)
- `WhiteChorus.do_something()` tries to cast the base class's pointer to a pointer to a `WhiteNoise`.

This should succeed, since the pointer was constructed as as pointer to a `WhiteNoise`. If this isn't working in your test case (and we haven't got a reproducible example here) then I think there might be a problem with the constructor of `WhiteChorus`.

Note that I've removed the term `Effect` from the end of all class names. Life is too short.